# Bar Button item not showing in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode7

I created a simple Bar button item in my project but it is not showing when I run it.      This is how I declare it

@IBOutlet weak var songSelectionBar: UIBarButtonItem!

Here is a screen shot of my project.  I am fairly new to swift so I know I am doing something that should be simple (or maybe not).

[image: the drop down menu should be placed next to select a song]

Here is some more code from the project.  This function returns the contents of the directory.  My understanding is that I should use a tableview to display the output of this function.  Can anyone point me to an example or show me how to do this?  Thanks

```
func getMusicFilesInDirectory() -> [String] {        
    //var wavFiles:[String]
    // We need just to get the documents folder url
    let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

    // now lets get the directory contents (including folders)
    do {
        let directoryContents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(directoryContents)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    // now filter the directory to extract only Wav Files

    do {
        let directoryUrls = try  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions())
        print(directoryUrls)
        let wavFilesDir = directoryUrls.filter(){ $0.pathExtension! == "wav" }.map{ $0.lastPathComponent! }
        wavFiles = ["Wav Music Files:\n" + wavFilesDir.description]
       } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
     return wavFiles
                                       }
```

Comment: is that a toolbar or tab bar ?

Comment: @Mr.T  I am trying to create a dropdown menu which does not exist in swift. So after reading about it I was told to use a Bar button. Maybe I should be using a different object. Not sure these stuff can get confusing when going from one language to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just declare the IBOutlet,not drag it out from IB,you should get rid of the "weak".
The IB has a strong reference to it's IBOutlet,so you must use it's IBOutlets with weak.
By contrast,if you manually declare an IBOutlet,you must keep a strong reference to it.

Comment: good point.  I just fixed it.  Still trying to wrap my head around how to get it to show up.